# Explicit template instantiation declaration does not generate destructors

Tags: c++, templates

I have noticed that explicit template instantiation does not instantiate destructors.

Please take a look at the code below:

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "templated_wrapper.hpp"
#include "user_1.hpp"

int main() {
    Templated<std::string> t{"main"};
    std::cout << t.get() << std::endl;

    user_1::use();
    return 0;
}
```

The `template.hpp` class:

```
#pragma once

template<typename T>
class Templated {
public:
    Templated(const T& t) : t_{t} {}
    const T& get() const { return t_; }
    void set(const T& t) { t_ = t; }
private:
    T t_;
};
```

The user class:
`user_1.hpp`:

```
#pragma once

namespace user_1 {
void use();
} // namespace user_1
```

`user_1.cpp`:

```
#include "user_1.hpp"

#include "templated_wrapper.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace user_1 {
void use() {
    Templated<std::string> t{"user 1"};
    std::cout << t.get() << std::endl;
}
} // namespace user_1
```

And finally, the wrapper where I declare the instantiation and define in the corresponding cpp.
`templated_wrapper.hpp`:

```
#pragma once
#include "template.hpp"
#include <string>

extern template class Templated<std::string>;
```

`templated_wrapper.cpp`:

```
#include "templated_wrapper.hpp"

template class Templated<std::string>;
```

After I build the program, I check the generated instantiation in every object file with `nm`, the results are below:

`main.o`:

```
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T main
                 U Templated<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::Templated(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
0000000000000000 W Templated<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::~Templated()
0000000000000000 W Templated<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::~Templated()
0000000000000000 n Templated<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::~Templated()
                 U Templated<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::get() const
```

`user_1.o`:

```
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T user_1::use()
                 U Templated<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::Templated(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
0000000000000000 W Templated<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::~Templated()
0000000000000000 W Templated<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::~Templated()
0000000000000000 n Templated<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::~Templated()
                 U Templated<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::get() const
```

And the wrapper.cpp:

```
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 W Templated<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::set(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
0000000000000000 W Templated<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::Templated(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
0000000000000000 W Templated<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::Templated(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
0000000000000000 n Templated<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::Templated(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
0000000000000000 W Templated<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::get() const
```

As you may see in the first two, all methods except destructors are marked as undefined (defined somewhere else) and in the wrapper they are weak, i.e. actually generated.
However, the destructors are not present in the wrapper while generated in the `main.o` and `user_1.o`.

Compiler:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Could you label each file with the name of the file.  As given, it is a bit difficult to know what the code blocks are without context.  Also `user_1.hpp` appears to be missing.

Comment: The destructors are implicitly defined, and that seems to change how the compiler handles them.

Comment: What's the problem?  Unless you've declared destructors, the compiler generates them only if and when it needs them.

Comment: @Eljay , fixed the post

Comment: @arayq2 I was sure that an explicit instantiation would generate *all* methods of a class. It seems that explicit instantiation still leaves some place for implicit instantiation.
Are you familiar with any resource explaining it?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, thank you for the reply, can you point to any resource mentioning this behavior?

Comment: @fsquirrel Have you tried comparing with an explicitly-defaulted default constructor? All your delcared methods are now dependent on `T`, and the compiler will need to know what `T` is to use the primary template as blueprint to generate definitions for the particular specializations which are instantiated. It could be interesting to see what the compiler does with a `Templated() = default;` ctor.

Comment: @dfrib, I've added a default dtor, the same result. The dtor becomes "undefined" only if I actually define it. As far as I understand the compiler knows everything about the class at the moment when it does instantiation.

Comment: @fsquirrel Note that I wrote default **ctor**, to compare to the dtor case. You are currently comparing member method which are dependent on `T` with the dtor special member functions. It may be interesting to see if you get the same behavior also for a explicitly-defaulted ctor.

Comment: What is the command line to compile `templated_wrapper.cpp`?

Comment: @dfrib, the same for the explicitly-defaulted default ctor: 
```
0000000000000000 W Templated<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::Templated()
```

Comment: @Eljay, I use cmake but this is the identical command with g++ only: `g++ -Wall -Wbuiltin-macro-redefined -pedantic -Werror -c ../main.cpp ../templated_wrapper.cpp ../user_1.cpp`

Comment: Using that compile command, the code provided generates 13 errors, and does not compile.

Comment: @Eljay, I forgot to include <string> in one of the files, my bad